# Passing params to controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im fairly new to RoR so I'm trying to learn by doing some projects. The current one I'm working on is app for gym trainers with clients. When I try to create a new assessment for a client it seems as if the client_id param isn't being passed to the assessments_controller.
This is the line:

```
<%= link_to 'New assessment', new_assessment_path(client_id: @client.id), class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
```

Error: Couldn't find Client with 'id'=

When on the new assessment view, however, in the debug area I see this:

```
--- !ruby/hash-with-ivars:ActionController::Parameters
elements:
  client_id: '1'
  controller: assessments
  action: new
ivars:
  :@permitted: false
```

When I then click 'create' the error occurs

assessment_controller:

```
 def create
   @assessment = Assessment.new(assessment_params)
   @assessment.client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @assessment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @assessment, notice: 'Assessment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assessment }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @assessment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Show all controller's code.

Comment: @alexkojin added

Comment: Do you have any before_action in controller that load client before action. Too look at log/development.log and there check the error line number.

Comment: @AlexKojin added before_action but didn't change anything

Comment: The params you showed is for the `#new` action, but your problem is that you didn't supply the param `:client_id` to the `#create` action. The bug is somewhere with your `#new` action or the form. You need to show these for us to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are assigning the `new_assessment_path(client_id: @client.id)` to new page and when submitting form the client id not passing to create action. There are many different solutions.

**1. Solution**

```
<%= link_to 'New assessment', new_assessment_path(client_id: @client.id), class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>

#assestment _form.html.erb file
<%= f.hidden_field_tag 'client_id', @client_id %>

#assessments_controller:
def new
   @assessment = Assessment.new
   @client_id = params[:client_id]
end

def create
   @assessment = Assessment.new(assessment_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @assessment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @assessment, notice: 'Assessment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assessment }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @assessment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

#add :client_id
def assessment_params
   params.require(:registration).permit(..., :client_id)
end
```